# iam updating my category and found error The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I Just wanna to creating some category(i am from indonesia). And i found a bug when i am just try updating my category.

This is my routes

[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S45Xw.png)

This is my controller

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF9gV.png)

this is my blade

```
@extends('admin.master')

@section('judul')
    Edit Kategori
@endsection

@section('content')
    <form action="/kategori" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
            @if($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mb-3">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h5><i class="icon fas fa-ban"></i> Error : </h5>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="judul" id="isi" placeholder="Judul" autocomplete="off" required value="{{ $kategori->judul }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="isi" id="isi" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Isi" class="form-control" style="resize:none;">{{ $kategori->isi }}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: Besides of not posting images of code, please tell us what exactly your problem(/"bug") and therefore your concrete question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your view form action with this one

```
<form method="post" action={{ route('kategori.update',$id) }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit route::get to route::put

```
Route::put($uri, $callback);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing

Comment: OP is using `Route::resource(...)`, that should already be handled

Answer (score 0):

Route Resource only handles put for update methods but not for create method so you should create new route as mentioned by @YaMus or work with post method. Reference https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller